# Primary Key- database

Tags: database, database-design

How do we define a primary key in a database which contains transactional data on bank loans/accounts.

For eg - if I take primary key as account no- there might be more than one row(transaction) for the same account no.

Comment: Why not use an auto increment id? Or a composite primary key between account no and another value.

Comment: Yes. Normally in this situation you generate a number to use because there is no naturally occurring primary key.

Comment: Each transaction has a unique transaction id which is assigned by either the application or the DBMS (might be a sequence, GUID, etc.). The account number in the transaction table will be a Foreign Key referencing the acocunts table.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similiar question, but could not find a convincing answer yet.
Bank transaction do not have a obvious primary key. There is no id you could use. Not even in the publicy available standards, i was not able to find sth.

But then i was thinking, i have the following option:

1. i could use the date and ordinal number withing the list of transaction to construct a key  like:

   `[('2019-01-01', 1), ('2019-01-01', 2)]`
   or
   `['2019-01-01_000001' '2019-01-01_000002)]`
2. and additionally do sth with the balance and create some kind of hash or just hash date, ordinal_number, balance to form a hash. There are severeal options.

Afterall i used `('2019-01-01', 1)` and additionally created a hash which i shortened to 5 digits.

For now it works, and transaction and ordnial numbers should never change otherwise i might want to change my bank, especially when the balance also changes afterwards :-D.

You can even do several updates per day and just take transactions that do not exists in your database yet.

Answer (score -2):

use auto incremented  column for primary key.